# Building SQL IN statement from listbox control

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, stringbuilder, sql-in

I'm trying to build a SQL query using `StringBuilder` and I've become stuck trying to do part of the `WHERE` clause.

I have a list box with a bunch of values and allows multiple selection. I need to iterate through the selected items and put then in an `IN` statement like...

```
WHERE SOME_FIELD IN ('Value','NextValue','AnotherValue')
```

so far I've written the code like this...

```
if (lstSalesGroup.SelectedItem != null)
{
    selectQuery.Append("AND SALES_GROUP IN (");
    foreach (ListItem item in lstSalesGroup.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
            selectQuery.Append("'" + item.Value + "',");
    }
    selectQuery.Append(")");
}
```

I need to test if the item is the last in the loop so that it doesn't put on the "," before the closing ")".

How can I do this? Or if there's a better way to build this part of the query please do suggest, I am still learning, we all have to start somewhere! :)

Eventually this will be a query for a part search.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of ways for doing that.

You can use [string.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) to remove the extra comma from the string or you can create a new string using [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) like

```
string InPartQuery = string.Join(",", lstSalesGroup.Items
                                          .Cast<ListItem>()
                                          .Where(t => t.Selected)
                                          .Select(r => "'" + r.Value + "'"));
```

Comment: +1 for laconic LINQ, but you should add filter by selected items

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much @Habib :) What is laconic LINQ? how is it different from regular LINQ?

Comment: @Stuart, nothing it is regular LINQ, its just the writing style :) see [define: laconic](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=laconic&aq=f&oq=laconic&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=define:+laconic&oq=define:+laconic&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.29766.36409.0.36503.17.15.1.1.1.0.850.6618.3-3j7j3j1.14.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.BAbGRnfHEgc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45175338,d.ZWU&fp=917cb835ff63700d&biw=1280&bih=899)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.Join` with some `Linq`

For clearity I've put the code in variables.

```
if (lstSalesGroup.SelectedItem != null)
{
    var queryStr = "AND SALES_GROUP IN ({0})";
    var selectedItemValues = (from itm in lstSalesGroup.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                              where itm.Selected
                              select String.Format("'{0}'", itm));
    selectQuery.Append(String.Format(queryStr, String.Join(",", selectedItemValues)));
}
```

Comment: You are missing quotes around values. And I don't sure if `itm` will not be of `object` type

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Thanks, I missed that so I've edited it. Should be alright now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using linq

```
selectQuery.Append("AND SALES_GROUP IN (");

selectQuery.Append(string.Join(",", lstSalesGroup.Items.Select(i => "'" + i.Value + "'")));    

selectQuery.Append(")");
```

This will solve your problem, but you have a problem with SQL injection here. I would strongly advice you to use parameters in your query.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I thought it was safe from injection if I'm programatically populating the select options?

Comment: This is a common mistake but there is a potential risk for SQL injection here. Imagine that someone somehow managed to get the value "') Drop table SomeTable;--" into your list. Can you see what your final query would look like? =)

Comment: ...something like my P45!!  I'll put all the final values into parameters. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (lstSalesGroup.SelectedItem != null)
{
    selectQuery.Append("AND SALES_GROUP IN (");
    var local = lstSalesGroup.Items.Where(c => c.Selected)
                       .Select(c => "'"+c.Value+"'")
                       .Aggregate((c,n) => c+ ", "+n);

   selectQuery.Append(local);            
   selectQuery.Append(")");
}
```

Look at [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Aggregate-Operators-c51b3869) example for more info on the `.Aggragate(...)` method

Comment: That will produce correct result, but I think that aggregating strings without `StringBuilder` will produce many unnecessary strings. Simple `String.Join` will be better here

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I agree. `string.Join` is simpler. I just didn't thought of it :) My mind is "linq'ed"

Comment: Here is a hint how to stay with LINQ, but avoid messing memory with strings `Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb,s) => sb.Append(s), sb => sb.ToString())` :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Darn interesting approach, never investigated that overload in `Aggregate`. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s As String = "'"
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        s = s & ListBox1.Items.Item(i) & "','"
    Next
```

Comment: This doesn't really look like C# ;-) And please provide some explanation, to improve your answer.

Comment: Question is about C#, this is Visual Basic.